# Getting filetype of netcat output?

Tags: encryption, netcat

How can I use the `file` command on an output from netcat?

For example:

```
nc 192.168.1.1 1234

dGhpcyBpcyBhIHNhbXBsZSBzdHJpbmc=
```

`dGhpcyBpcyBhIHNhbXBsZSBzdHJpbmc=` being the output, (sample base64 for the purpose of the example).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the result through `file -`. Like most programs, `-` can be used to refer to stdin.

But do note that base64 is just "ascii text".